# Fastest way to calculate how many straight lines required to intersect points?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I was doing a coding interview and even though I was able to solve it, I got low score on the performance and I thought I'd asked for improvements.

## Question:

Input is array of points on a graph. E.g `[(-1, -2), (1, 2), (2, 4), (2, 3)]`

From point `(0, 0)`, how many straight lines do you need to draw to intersect all points?

## Solution:

I solved this in O(n) by looping through all points and storing the ratio in a set, then returning the number of items in the set. So for example, `(1, 2)` and `(2, 4)` have the same ratio, so a single line can pass through them.

How would you solve this in a faster way than O(n)?

### My Code:

```py
def countRays(points):
  positiveRatios = set()
  negativeRatios = set()
  for point in points:
    x, y = point
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
      symbol = "-"
    else:
      symbol = "+"

    ratios = positiveRatios if x >= 0 else negativeRatios
    if x == 0:
      ratios.add( (symbol, 1,) )
    else:
      ratios.add( (symbol, y/x,) )
  return len(positiveRatios) + len(negativeRatios)
```

Comment: Why is (-1,-2) and (1,2) not on the same line? Typically a line in mathematics extends infinitely in both directions.

Comment: Because all lines are drawn from 0,0.

Comment: So you actually mean a half-line or ray.

Comment: Yes @Henry, it's rays.

Comment: Is your algorithm correct? Doesn't it treat points (0, 1) and (1,1) as the same point (adding `("+", 1,)` to `positiveRatios`)?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be solved faster than O(n). Each point can give rise to a new line so you have to look at each one at least once.